# 2 questions about function pointer in c

Tags: c, function

I have two questions

1.I saw that

```
int (*Ptr)(int,int);
Ptr=someOtherFuncion;
```

Its not should be like that?

```
Ptr=&someOtherFuncion;
```

2.I learn that function pointer its for callback
like that

```
    someOtherFunction(functionPointer)
```

what is the differeence if I will put a regular function that is not pointer?

Comment: One question per question please: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of a function decays almost immediately to a pointer to the function, so `someOtherFunction` decays to the same pointer that `&someOtherFunction` gives you explicitly. In fact, the operand of the address-of operator (`&`) is one of the few places were the decay *doesn't* happen.

This has amusing consequences: Even if you dereference the function pointer, it decays again right away. So the following are all equivalent:

```
someOtherFunction(1, 2);
(*someOtherFunction)(1, 2);
(**someOtherFunction)(1, 2);
(***someOtherFunction)(1, 2);
```

So, if you feel unwell assigning to a function pointer without an explicit address-of, by all means put the `&` in there, but you don't have to.

To address the second part of the question: A function is *always* called through a function pointer, but because of the above-mentioned instant decay, normal functions can be called just the same way as function pointers.

Comment: About the second part
so if regular function are like function pointer
why should I use function pointers?

Comment: @user1801625: I never claimed you should :-) But imagine you want a function to be variable, like a call-back, or a handler, or a thread entry point, or something linked at runtime...

Comment: so regular function can't be a callback what does it matter if its variable?does it for convenience?

Comment: Wait, slow down. Think about the function that *consumes* the call-back. Look at `qsort` if you will.