# function pointer typedef

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

What is the difference between

```
typedef double F(double)
```

and

```
typdedef double (*FPT)(double);
```

?

It seems to me that I can pass both as arguments to a function, i.e.

```
bar1(FPT f);
bar2(F f);
```

but while I can do

```
FPT f = &foo;
```

I can not do

```
F f = foo;
```

i.e. I can not create variables of type F?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right in many ways. `F` is a function type, and `FPT` is a function pointer type.

If you have an object of function type, you can take its address and get a function pointer. However, objects of function type aren't real, first-class C++ objects. Only actual functions are of such a type, and you can't create an object that is a function (other than by declaring a function!) and thus you cannot assign to it (as in `F f = foo;`).

The only way you can refer to a function is via a function pointer or reference:

```
FPT f1 = &foo;
F * f2 = &foo;
F & f3 = foo;
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242329/596781).

Note that for a callback I would prefer the reference type over the pointer type, because it's more natural compared to how you pass any other variable, and because you can apply address-of and decay to the reference and get the pointer, which you can't do with a pointer:

```
double callme(F & f, double val)       // not: "F *" or "FPT"
{
    return f(val);

    // "&f" and "std::decay<F>::type" still make sense
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In parameter lists, function types decay to the appropriate function pointer type, such that a function of the same type can be passed as in an argument list, itself decaying to the same pointer type.

This works the same for arrays; `void foo(int arg[4])` has actual first argument type `int *`.

> #### 8.3.5 Functions [dcl.fct]
>
> 5 - [...] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type "array of `T`" or "function returning `T`" is adjusted to be "pointer to `T`" or "pointer to function returning `T`," respectively. [...]

The use of a function type in a declaration is covered in the same section:

> 10 - A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function.