# Explain this gcc functions' typization behaviour

Tags: c, types, syntax, function-pointers

In my code I have to use several functions as *lambdas*, such as you should provide, for example, to `qsort`.
So when I was passing a function of type `int`, program was working fine. But when I added also another function of type `double`, the error message appeared:

> 1.c:44:29: error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'double *' and 'double')

from the line:

```
return (*getter)(a) < target
```

Where `getter` is the pointer to:

```
double get_sex(struct human* a) { // it's the second function I've passed
    return a->sex;
}
```

The only difference between two functions I've passed is that the first one is `int` and the second is `double`.

```
sometype somefunction (some parameters,
        int *comparator(struct human*, double, double *(struct human*)),
        double *getter(struct human*) ) {
    ....
}
```

I started to inspect it with `sizeof` and found, that somehow the code `(*getter)(*a)` returns 4 bytes instead of 8, so it must be a pointer instead of double. That's why I had that error message.
I went to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) for an example and found additional `()`. I've added them, and now it returns 8 bytes and works fine.

```
        double (*getter)(struct human*) ) {
```

So the question is: **why should I add parentheses around `getter` but not around `comparator`? Is the reason that function returns `double` instead of `int`?!**
It's something about syntax detail I never heard about.

(I use the compiler that I found on my Windows already installed – from the Perl interpreter Strawberry)

Comment: You should post a small, complete example that shows the problem. The answer is likely to depend on a small detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from that:

```
double *getter(struct human*)
```

is implicitly converted to:

```
double *(*getter)(struct human*)
```

This is why you get error because you cannot compare `(double *)` and `double`

You do not have some problems with `int` because your pointer `(int *)` is cast to `int` and comparison can be done. However, your compiler should warn you about implicit conversion from pointer to integer.

The problem here is that I have never seen that you can declare a *function pointer* parameter in such a way. I tried to write a piece of code and apparently it works. However, this might be some non-standard behavior of GCC. Correct way to define pointers to functions is with parentheses. I.e.

```
double (*getter)(struct human*)  /* 'getter' is a pointer to function taking
                                    struct human and returning double */
```

Answer (score 2):

In this expression:

```
int myfunc( double *getter(struct human*) );
```

...`getter` has *function type* (function type returning pointer to double). While in this:

```
int myfunc( double (*getter)(struct human*) );
```

...it has *function pointer type* (pointer to function type returning double).

Function types and function pointer types work *essentially* the same way because function types decay to function pointer types almost instantly in most cases. I believe this is what the standard says here: (C99, 6.3.2.1/4):

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except
>   when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to
>              function returning type’’.

So, your expression:

```
return (*getter)(a) < target;
```

...decays `getter` from a function type to a function pointer type (of type `double * (*)(struct human*)`), as per the standard, though you wanted `double (*)(struct human*)`.

You should get a warning, as soon as you pass your function to `somefunction`, that they are of incompatible types, something like:

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘somefunction’ from incompatible pointer type

Also, see this [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258806/492901), [as well as this interesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242329/492901).

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide all of your code, so I'm just guessing that you're doing something like:

```
if (comparator(h, val, getter)) { ... }
```

where comparator includes:

```
return getter(h) < val;
```

or something like that.

The key here is that the result of getter is used by the operator `<`. The result of comparator, on the other hand, is *converted to a boolean* (well, not really: this is C. But it's the same idea.) And you can implicitly convert any pointer to a boolean (that is, an integer), without raising any warnings.

So what happens is:

1. comparator returns an `int`, but
2. The caller is expecting an `int*`. That's ok, though; pointers and integers are returned the same way.
3. The caller now wants to use the `int*` as though it were an `int`, which is also OK.

So no error.

And furthermore, the zero-ness of the return value is preserved by the accidental cast and by the implicit conversion, so as a bonus, you get the right answer.